# What does "constructors are not inherited" exactly mean?

Tags: java

I read somewhere that in Java "constructors are not inherited".

On the other hand, I also read that if I don't explicitly call **super**, Java automatically calls the super class constructor with no arguments (such a constructor must exist in this case).

Isn't automatically calling the super class constructor (with no arguments) a form of inheritance?

What does "constructors are not inherited" exactly mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that you cannot create a subclass, using a constructor of the super class-if the subclass did not also declared it. An example;

```
class A {
  A() {}
  A(String s) {}
}

class B extends A {    
}
```

Now you cannot do this:

```
B b = new B("testing");
```

Comment: The code in your answer won't compile because class B has an implicit default parameterless constructor which attempts to invoke a similar constructor in A, but class A, since it defines a constructor, does not define this default constructor.

Comment: I have edited your answer to add an explicit parameterless constructor to class A.

Answer (score 6):

It means just because your superclass has a contructor doesn't mean the subclass will automatically get the same constructor; you have to define it manually.

The default constructor is kind of an exception and kind of isn't. It's automatically defined for you, but it's not really "inherited" because it's still part of the subclass; it's not a member of the superclass.